# Plublish zip file of you .net app through TeamCity Artifactory (Jfrog)

Tags: nuget, teamcity, artifactory, artifacts, jfrog-cli

I am new to working with Artifactory (Jfrog).

I have a dotnet core application (github), that builds with each code commit using Teamcity.

How can I publish the application zip file to Artifactory.

PS: I have installed the Artifactory plugin and tested the connection between Teamcity and Jfrog.

What should I do next.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Using+File+Specs on how to use the File Spec syntax in the Artifactory Plugin for TeamCity.

This is what a sample Upload Spec would look like:

```
{
  "files": [
    {
      "pattern": "**\*app.Api*.nupkg",
      "target": "app-dev",
      "recursive": "false"
    }
  ]
}
```

For your case, you'd need use a spec similiar to this but change the following:

- `pattern` to the relative path to your `.zip` file
- `target` to the name of your repo in Artifactory
- `recursive` set to `False` (this is to do with properties which isn't relevant)